# Object Cannot Be Cast to ArrayList

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, classcastexception

I'm having some trouble with reading an arraylist from file in Java.

I have a "User" class which implements Serializable, so when I go to save an ArrayList of these users it seems to work fine - but when I try read them it's a different story.

ava.lang.ClassCastException: User cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

The Code I have for reading in is as follows ..

```
 private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

public void readList() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    System.out.println("Trying to read list..");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("userList.txt");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    System.out.println("Created Streams....");
    userList = ((ArrayList<User>)ois.readObject());
    ois.close();
}
```

Has anyone has similar problems or know how to help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: `"Has anyone has similar problems"` -- you've got a bug in your program, and we've all experienced that. You need to also show how you serialize the data as your deserialization is not being done in a way that is symmetric with your serialization. It looks like you're serializing the data as a User object and then trying to read it in as an ArrayList, which it's not.

Comment: please provide sample code on how your are serializing/storing object

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize an `ArrayList` out of the stream, then you must be sure to serialize an ArrayList into the stream. The way you've serialized your `User` objects, you would be required to deserialize them like so:

```
private List<User> userList;

public void readList() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("Trying to read list..");
    this.userList = new ArrayList<User>();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("userList.txt");
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        System.out.println("Created Streams....");

        // you would want to store this number in your object stream as userList.size()
        int numberOfUsersSerialized = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsersSerialized; i++) {
            userList.add((User) ois.readObject());
        }
    } finally {
        fis.close();
    }
}
```